# How to test jdbi BinderFactory

Tags: java, junit, jdbi

I have a custom binder:

```
@BindingAnnotation(CustomBinder.CustomBinderFactory.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface CustomBinder {
    class CustomBinderFactory implements BinderFactory<CustomBinder> {
        @Override
        public Binder<CustomBinder, Entity> build(CustomBinder annotation) {
            return (q, bind, arg) -> {
                // implement
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test for this; how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. First of all, you can write a simple jUnit test and mock (or, preferably, instantiate) `CustomBinder` class.

If you want to add write an integration test, your integration tests might use this annotation - and you can assert the result.

But I'd start with a simple unit test. Take a look at this article: https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation